# How to reuse geometry node with animation keyframe?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I have two objects and 1 geometry node with animation keyframes. I'd like object 1 use the geometry node from keyframe 1 to 250 and object 2 use the same geometry node from key frame from 251 to 500.

The issue is once I changed the keyframe for the object 2, the keyframe for object 1 is also changed. So object 1 and 2 are using the same keyframe.

How do I fix this? Ideally I want to have a input parameter "start frame" that set the start frame of the animation.

My file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/JLeKxq5R

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Expose your value into **Group input** node:

[image]

And animate in the modifier:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The answer from Crantisz is the best way to do it, I guess. Here's just an addition that might be helpful for the future. I've seen there's another keyframed animation on the *Color Ramp* in your node tree, the left slider with the black color moves from position 0.0 to 0.99 via keyframes.

Although you might not need a different frame range on that for both objects in this example, just in case you want to control them separately: it would be the best to connect them to the *Group Input* just like the other value in Crantisz' answer. The problem with a *Color Ramp* is that you have no inputs for slider positions or colors.

But in a simple case like this where you only have two sliders with greyscale values between 0 and 1 you can easily replace the *Color Ramp* with a *Map Range* node:

- the *Value* input corresponds to the *Fac* input of the *Color Ramp*
- *From Min* is the position of the left slider
- *From Max*  the position of the right slider
- *To Min* is the greyscale color of the left slider, for example black = 0
- *To Max* is the greyscale value of the right slider, e.g. white = 1
- and the *Result* output gives the value corresponding to the ramp's *Color* output

[image: color ramp substitution]

So you could connect all inputs of the *Map Range* node to the outside of the GN modifier like Crantisz did with that one value. This way you have external control about the positions and greyscale values as if they were sliders of a *Color Ramp*.

In your file where you animated the left slider position it would be sufficient to connect the *From Min* socket to the *Group Input* node. Then you can duplicate your object and animate that value independently as well.

[image: from min controller]